# How to create a custom Authorize attribute for multiple policies in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to authorize an action controller could access by multiple policies.

.e.g:

```
[Authorize([Policies.ManageAllCalculationPolicy,Policies.ManageAllPriceListPolicy]]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id){}
```

Thank a lot.

Comment: IMHO, just add a 3rd policy...

Answer (score 21):

For multiple policies, you could implement your own AuthorizeAttribute.

- AuthorizeMultiplePolicyAttribute

  ```
   public class AuthorizeMultiplePolicyAttribute:TypeFilterAttribute
   {
   public AuthorizeMultiplePolicyAttribute(string policies,bool IsAll):base(typeof(AuthorizeMultiplePolicyFilter))
   {
       Arguments = new object[] { policies,IsAll};
   }
   }
  ```
- AuthorizeMultiplePolicyFilter

  ```
   public class AuthorizeMultiplePolicyFilter: IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
   {
   private readonly IAuthorizationService _authorization;
   public string _policies { get; private set; }
   public bool _isAll { get; set; }
   public AuthorizeMultiplePolicyFilter(string policies, bool IsAll,IAuthorizationService authorization)
   {
       _policies = policies;
       _authorization = authorization;
       _isAll = IsAll;
   }

   public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
   {

       var policys = _policies.Split(";").ToList();
       if (_isAll)
       {
           foreach (var policy in policys)
           {
               var authorized = await _authorization.AuthorizeAsync(context.HttpContext.User, policy);
               if (!authorized.Succeeded)
               {
                   context.Result = new ForbidResult();
                   return;
               }
           }
       }
       else
       {
           foreach (var policy in policys)
           {
               var authorized = await _authorization.AuthorizeAsync(context.HttpContext.User, policy);
               if (authorized.Succeeded)
               {
                   return;
               }
           }
           context.Result = new ForbidResult();
           return;
       }
   }
   }
  ```
- Add Policy you want on Startup

  ```
   services.AddAuthorization(options =>
       {

           options.AddPolicy("ManageAllCalculationPolicy", policy =>
                   policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
                       context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "BadgeId")));

           options.AddPolicy("ManageAllPriceListPolicy", policy =>
                   policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
                       context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "aaaa")));
       });
  ```
- Authorization based on one of the policies

  ```
   [AuthorizeMultiplePolicy("ManageAllCalculationPolicy;ManageAllPriceListPolicy", false)]
  ```
- Authorization based on all policies

  ```
   [AuthorizeMultiplePolicy("ManageAllCalculationPolicy;ManageAllPriceListPolicy", true)]
  ```

Comment: I used this with this code ;   
context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("Index", "Error", new { code = 403 });
and worked perfectly, thanks for your affords

Comment: If you want to use AND you can just use two Authorize attributes.
[Authorize("ManageAllCalculationPolicy")]
[Authorize("ManageAllPriceListPolicy")]

Comment: Visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.1 Now it's quite simple the answer and it's not necessary to implement more code, Microsoft did it for us.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot add multiple policies as a list with condition `or`. I think NetCore does not support that.

Try to create a new policy.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("BadgeEntry", policy =>
        policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
            context.User.HasClaim(c =>
                (c.Type == ClaimTypes.BadgeId ||
                 c.Type == ClaimTypes.TemporaryBadgeId) &&
                 c.Issuer == "https://microsoftsecurity")));
});
```

**Reference:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1#why-would-i-want-multiple-handlers-for-a-requirement

Comment: Now It's possible : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 2):

Worked like a charm!!

Here is my part of code in Startup.ConfigureServices

```
services.AddAuthorization(config =>
                {
                    config.AddPolicy(Policies.Admin, Policies.AdminPolicy());
                    config.AddPolicy(Policies.Register, Policies.RegistradorPolicy());
                });
```

And, for example.. policies are:

```
public class Policies
{
        public const string Admin = 'Admin';
        public const string Register = 'Register';

        public static AuthorizationPolicy AdminPolicy()
        {
            return new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().RequireRole(Admin).Build();
        }

        public static AuthorizationPolicy RegisterPolicy()
        {
            return new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().RequireRole(Register).Build();
        }

}
```

Then in controllers..

```
[HttpGet]
        [AuthorizeMultiplePolicy(Policies.Admin + ";" + Policies.Register, false)]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Accion>> GetAll(){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple policies like that

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("BadgeEntry", PolicyClaimCheck.Any, new string[2] { "VT102","RS102" });
    options.AddPolicy("Notification", PolicyClaimCheck.All, new string[2] { "XTX101","NT102" });
});
```

If it is enough to have one, you should use `PolicyClaimCheck.Any` or If it must have all, you should use `PolicyClaimCheck.All`

Comment: Which .NET version is this? `PolciyClaimCheck` is not available in .net core 3.1

Answer (score 0):

```
[Authorize(Roles = "HRManager,Finance")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id){}
```

For more info visit:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.1